# Syndetic sets and Banach limits: reference request

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

First of all, let us give a few definitions. Suppose that $A$ is a subset of natural numbers. We say that $A$ is syndetic if there is a constant $M$ such that every set of $M$ consecutive natural numbers contains an element of $A$. We also say that $A$ is piecewise syndetic if there is some number $M$ such that there is a sequence $N_k$ such that every set of $M$ consecutive natural numbers in $[N_k,N_k+k]$ contains an element of $A$.

Next, a Banach limit $\phi:\ell^\infty\to \mathbb C$ is a positive shift-invariant linear functional such that $\phi(x)=c$ for every sequence $x_n$ with $x_n\to c$ for $n\to +\infty$. Upper and lower Banach densities $D^+(A)$ and $D^{-}(A)$ of $A$ are supremum and infimum of $\phi(1_A)$ over all Banach limits, where $1_A$ is the indicator function of $A$.

It is possible to establish the following results:

1. The set $A$ is syndetic iff $D^-(A)>0$
2. For $A$ to be piecewise syndetic it is necessary to have $D^+(A)>0$ and sufficient to have $D^+(A)=1$
3. The set $B$ is not piecewise syndetic iff for any syndetic $A$ the set $A\setminus B$ is also syndetic
4. If $A$ is not piecewise syndetic and $D^+(A)=\alpha$ then there is no set $B$ with $D^+(B)=D^-(B)=\alpha$ and $A\subset B$.

I would like to know if these are well-known results and is there a paper that contains them. Some or even all of the four can probably be generalized to semigroups, but I'm interested in these results for $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Statements 1, 2, and 3 are well known and can be generalized appropriately to semigroups. As for statement 4, I don't recognize it off the top of my head.

To say more about 1, 2, and 3, I don't know original sources for $\mathbb{N}$, but I think most results like this are rightfully considered folklore at this point. There are general statements for semigroups in [*Notions of Size and Combinatorial
Properties of Quotient Sets in Semigroups*](http://nhindman.us/research/quotient.pdf) by Bergelson, Hindman, and McCutcheon. See Theorems 2.6 and 2.7 for example.

Maybe it is worth saying that statements 1 and 2 become relatively short and straightforward exercises if one defines upper and lower Banach density in terms of Folner sequences instead of linear functionals. This is one way to isolate all of the heavier machinery from analysis and put it entirely into the proof that the Folner definition of these densities agrees with the one you have given. For semigroups, this is covered in the paper [*Density and invariant means in left amenable semigroups*](http://nhindman.us/research/densitymeans.pdf) by Hindman and Strauss (see Theorems 2.14 and 2.12).

For example, call a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ **thick** if it contains a translate of every finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Then it is easy to show that a set is syndetic if and only if its complement is not thick. So statement (1) is equivalent to saying that a set $A$ is thick if and only if $D^+(A)=1$. The latter statement is Proposition 1.21 in Paterson's book *Amenability*. The proof there is done directly from invariant means and involves nontrivial analysis.